# Library not found with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm trying to integrate Flurry into my App and I keep getting the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lFlurry_5.1.0
```

I am installing with Cocoapods (0.33.1)

Comment: hey, did you try my solution? If there is a problem please let me know or accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a linker flag `-lFlurry_5.1.0` added by pods to the project and it does not resolve.

The solution is to link against this library in your targets build phases as shown below. You can do this by clicking the '+' button below 'Link With Binary Libraries'. The library is located at (PROJECT_DIR)/Pods/FlurrySDK/Flurry/Flurry_5.1.0.a

After adding this, you need to remove -lFlurry_5.1.0 flag from 'Other Linker Flags' under 'Build Settings' tab for your target.

Below are some screenshots for these steps.

[image: build phases after pod installation]
[image: build phases after adding flurry library]
[image: linker flags after pod installation]
[image: linker flags after removing the flag]